# Dirichlet energy of a circle graph

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following is exercise 7.10(c) in *Introduction to Applied Linear Algebra* by Boyd & Vandenberghe.

> Suppose that $G$ is a graph such that there are $n$ vertices in a "circle". That is, $v_i$ is connected to $v_{i+1}$ via a single edge for $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, and $v_n$ is connected back to $v_1$ by a single edge.
>
> Given an $n$-vector $v$ of potentials, what is the Dirichlet energy $D(v) = \| A^Tv\|^2$? ($A$ is the incidence matrix of $G$, as described in the text.)

---

**My solution so far:** After doing a little bit of algebra, I came up with
$$
D(v) = 2\biggr(\biggr[\sum_i v_i^2\biggr] - [v_1v_2 + \dots + v_nv_1]\biggr).
$$

**What I don't understand:**

1. *Is this correct?* The algebra seemed pretty straightforward, but I
   might have made a mistake.
2. *What is the right way to interpret this?* My interpretation is currently just that if adjacent nodes on the circle have similar potentials, the left term will be close to the right term (because e.g. $v_1^2 \approx v_1v_2$). The opposite is true if adjacent nodes have very different potentials. This intuitively makes sense, but is there something deeper going on here that I should take away from this problem?

Comment: What is $A$? The adjacency matrix of $G$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, yes, I edited the question to reflect your clarification.

Comment: Why are you placing the title of the book in the title? The title is supposed to be descriptive, not a reference list.